# Play Framework 2 view declaration

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am looking at a Play Framework 2 view that starts with the following declarations:

```
@()

@main("Product Form")
```

I understand the call @main("Product Form") is passing a String object to the main template. What's with the `@()` call though? Is it required to declare that if the template is not receiving any arguments from its caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first line you need to declare parameters of the view (which is a Scala function as you know from the [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTemplates)) however if view doesn't get any params most probably you can remove the `@()` line without any problem.